# how to show a error message when custom exception was thrown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I just started right now with the topic `exceptionhandling`. I read alot of positiv stuff about it, so I thought I should do the same, because my current technique using errorcodes is really ugly...

Okay we have following scenario: A user typed his password in a `textbox`. After pressing the login button, he gets an positiv or negativ message.

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtBoxUserPassword/>
<Button x:Name="btnLogin" Click="btnLogin_Click">Login</Button>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
private void btnCT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     DataBase db = new DataBase();
     db.IsPasswordCorrect(this.txtBoxUserPassword.Text);

     // How can I catch here the exception from the class to 
     // show the error notification?
}
```

`DataBase.cs`

```
public class DataBase{
     public void IsPasswordCorrect(string password)
     {
          try{
              if(password != "fooBar")
              {
                  throw new InvalidPasswordException("You entered the wrong password. Try it again.");
              }
              else
              {
                  /*
                     ...
                  */
              }
          }
          catch(InvalidPasswordException ex){
              // What should I do here? I want to give the user an 
              // error message with the content "You entered the wrong   
              // password. Try it again."
          }
     }
}
```

`InvalidPasswordException.cs`

```
public class InvalidPasswordException: Exception
{
    public InvalidPasswordException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's the first time I using `exceptions`. Hopefully you can help me a bit. Thanks!

### Edit

I have this `switch/case construct` inside my `public void btnCT_Click()`.

```
switch (CheckString("EnteredString"))
{
    case 1:
        MessageBox.Show("Error 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        MessageBox.Show("Error 2");
        break;
    case 3:
        MessageBox.Show("Error 3");
        break;
    case 0:
        MessageBox.Show("Successful");
        break;
    }
```

Here is my method from another class. The classname is not important.

```
public int CheckString(string enteredString)
{
    if(enteredString length is larger 25 chars)
        return 1;
    else if(enteredString contains special characters)
        return 2;
    else if(enteredString dosent contain any number)
        return 3; 
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just remove the try/catch inside the IsPasswordCorrect and let the exception bubble up to the calling method (btnCT_Click). Add a try/catch there and show a message box with the Exception.Message property

Comment: Thanks for the comment Steve. Is that the common way?

Comment: Exceptions are costly to handle in terms of performance and should be used only for _exceptional_ reasons. You don't use them to drive your code. In this context the best method is to return a true/false value

Comment: Well use a global string with the error message. (Or a method inside the Database class that returns the LastErrorMessage) But perhaps you should provide more details about the context of the problem now.

Comment: Okay, true. But my problem is, that I check inside a method the validation of a string. It's about 5-10 `if else statements`. For this method is a return value of true/false not possible, because there should be 5-10 different messages. Thats why the method returns an int. I defined some error codes for this. After the methods return the error code, I check inside the button method the returned errorcode, to display the error message. This method is very ... . That's why I thought `exceptions` would be cleaner. What should I do instead of using `exceptions` in this scenario?

Comment: Okay, I added some code. Thats my current way to solve different error cases.

Comment: As I have explained in the answer below, I don't follow this approach but set an error message in the class that do the checking and if any error results I read a LastErrorMessage from the same class.

Comment: Thats much better, thanks! I have to ask it again sorry... Is that a good way as you explained it? Or is there a better and cleaner one?

Comment: I am not sure how to define _better_ or _cleaner_ in this context but I am pretty sure that exceptions are not the way to go when you are in control of the error situation and how to handle it.

Comment: Okay, thanks alot Steve! It's definitely cleaner then my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that I have to say is that you don't need a custom exception just for this. Looking just to the method's name (`IsPasswordCorrect`) anyone would expect this method to return a true/false boolean value not an exception.

So you could have a simpler

```
public class DataBase
{
     public bool IsPasswordCorrect(string password)
     {
          if(password != "fooBar")
             return false;
          else
             return true;
     }
}

.... at the UI level ....
if(!db.IsPasswordCorrect("notA_fooBar"))
   MessageBox.Show("You entered the wrong password. Try again");
else
   ....
```

However, if you really need to thrown an exception (remember that this is a costly operation in terms of performances) then do not catch it in the same method where you throw it but let it bubble up to reach the calling code

```
 public bool IsPasswordCorrect(string password)
 {
      if(password != "fooBar")
         throw new InvalidPasswordException("You entered the wrong password. Try again");
      ....
 }
```

and in the calling code (at the UI level) add the try catch blocks

```
private void btnCT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {

          DataBase db = new DataBase();
          db.IsPasswordCorrect(this.txtBoxUserPassword.Text);

          // If you reach this point the password is correct
          // But it is ugly and unclear to any reader....

     }
     catch(InvalidPasswordException ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
```

In any case exceptions should be used only for *exceptional* reasons. You don't use them to drive your code. In this context the best method is to return a true/false value.

---

When the failure reasons are complex I usually use this approach

```
bool ok = true;
ok = database.IsPasswordCorrect("fooBar");
if(ok) ok = database.Method1();
if(ok) ok = database.Method2();
if(ok) ok = database.Method3();

if(!ok)
   MessageBox.Show(database.LastErrorMessage);

public class Database
{
    public string LastErrorMessage { get; set; } 
    public bool Method1()
    {
        if(errorFoundForReason1)  
        {
             LastErrorMessage = "Error found for reason1";
             return false;
        }
        if(errorFoundForReason2)  
        {
             LastErrorMessage = "Error found for reason2";
             return false;
        }
        ....
        return true;
    }
}
```

Of course, every boolean method in the database class, when there is a reason to fail and before returning false, sets a global variable with the exact error message involved in the failure so the client code could handle easily the message when it has finished the calls.